# how to rebuild micropython with selected module?

Tags: python, stm32, micropython

I'm a bit new to MicroPython, Scripting languages, etc. So currently, I'm working on a project in which I'm using NUCLEO-G431RB(128kb flash and 32kb ram). STM32G43RB is a low-memory microcontroller. Hence, officially, no MicroPython file firmware file is available for this board.

As Micropython is an open-source platform, the code files are available on the website. Therefore, I wanted to know how I could compile Micropython source code with only selected modules (basic hardware peripheral modules) and eliminate all unnecessary modules (Bluetooth, network, etc.).

My overall goal is to have a bare minimum stack (which I can upload on the low-memory controller as well) of Micropython so that I can run a basic code dealing with hardware peripherals and like that. Any lead, hint or link would be helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my requirement at all. Please check https://micropython.org/, https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/develop/gettingstarted.html, and https://micropython.org/download/. You'll see a lot of pre-developed firmware available for the STM32 series controller. There is one available NUCLEO-G474RE (https://micropython.org/download/NUCLEO_G474RE/), and It has a similar core and architecture (The only difference is that this controller comes with higher flash and ram).

Comment: Micropython is built with C. If you know C, you will be able to understand the make file, the linker file to understand how each components/sub modules are put together, you can then to modify the lexer/interpreter in the  source code accordingly to remove the functions you don’t want to support. All the “lead, hint or link” are already in micropython source code you linked to.

Comment: BTW, micropython requires 256k of code space and 16k of RAM, by removing a few modules will probably not be able to achieve 50% reduction to fit into 128k flash of NUCLEO-G431RB. There is probably a reason why mocropython only supports selective boards.

Comment: Thank you @hcheung! Now at least, I know where to look. I'll proceed step by step with caution. On success, I'll upload the complete method.

Answer (score 1):

The key to the answer is `py/mpconfig.h`. That file lists all PP symbols which can conditionally enable the core code. In your own port's config file, normally named mpconfigport.h, you then `#define MICROPY_SOME_FEATURE 0` to disable the feature.